# Hibernate merge parent with detached child

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I`m stuck on a problem with merging entity with one detached child entity in its collection. It throws exception: 
**org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: com.adastragrp.cmsms.data.SeedNumber**

You can see in this "test()" method that I fetch some Queue from DB an take its childs. They are in detached state when they are sent to "saveQueue()" method. In this method I add them to other Queue. When merging this queue, hibernate throws the exception.

How can I make it work? Thanks for any answer or explanations.

```
    private void test() {
        List<SeedNumber> list = loadQueue();
        saveQueue(list);
    }

    @Transactional
    private List<SeedNumber> loadQueue() {
        return queueDAO.find("SECONDARY").getSeedNumbers();
    }

    @Transactional
    private void saveQueue(List<SeedNumber> detachedSeeds) {
        Queue q = queueDAO.find("DEFAULT");

        List<SeedNumber> seeds = new ArrayList<>();
        SeedNumber sn = new SeedNumber();
        sn.setPhoneNumber("123456");
        sn.setQueue(q);
        seeds.add(sn);
        for(SeedNumber s : detachedSeeds) {
            s.setQueue(q);
            seeds.add(s);
        }

        q.setSeedNumbers(seeds);            

        q = queueDAO.save(q);
    }
```

DAO Code:

```
public Queue save(Queue entity) {
    if (entity == null) {
        LOG.info("queue is null");
        return null;
    }
    if (getEntityManager().contains(entity)) {
        return entity;
    }

    entity = getEntityManager().merge(entity);

    return entity;
}
```

This is the parent class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CMSMS_QUEUE")
public class Queue {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID", length = 40)
    private String id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "queue", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<SeedNumber> seedNumbers;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }   

    public List<SeedNumber> getSeedNumbers() {
        return seedNumbers;
    }

    public void setSeedNumbers(List<SeedNumber> seedNumbers) {
        this.seedNumbers = seedNumbers;
    }
}
```

This is the child class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CMSMS_SEED_NUMBER")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "SeedNumberSeq", sequenceName = "CMSMS_SEED_NUMBER_SEQ", allocationSize = 1)
public class SeedNumber {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "SeedNumberSeq")
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "PHONE_NUMBER")
    private String phoneNumber;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "QUEUE_ID")
    private Queue queue;


    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getPhoneNumber() {
        return phoneNumber;
    }

    public void setPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }

    public Queue getQueue() {
        return queue;
    }

    public void setQueue(Queue queue) {
        this.queue = queue;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the following piece of code is problematic:

```
if (getEntityManager().contains(entity)) {
    return entity;
}

entity = getEntityManager().merge(entity);

return entity;
```

If you want the `cascade=MERGE` to propagate to the list of seed numbers, you shouldn't skip the call to `merge`.

IMHO, a much clearer solution would be to implement `saveQueue` like so:

```
private void saveQueue(List<SeedNumber> detachedSeeds) {
    Queue queue = queueDAO.find("DEFAULT");

    SeedNumber sn = new SeedNumber();
    sn.setPhoneNumber("123456");
    sn.setQueue(q);
    seedNumberDao.saveSeed(sn);
    for (SeedNumber seed : detachedSeeds) {
        seed.setQueue(queue);
        seedNumberDao.saveSeed(seed);
    }
}
```

As a side note, putting `@Transactional` on private methods has no effect.

Comment: Yes, you're right :) I did not realize I skip merge when the object is already in PersistanceContext. Thanks a  lot! Regarding the @Transactional annotation, I use Maven AspectJ plugin, so it works also on private methods.